# AChartEngine display x-axis label above the axis

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I know how to set the AChartEngine Y-axis label location by using `mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);`. But I could not find a similar setup for the X-axis. Is there something special I have to do in order to display the x-axis labels above the axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
renderer.setXLabelsPadding(-30);
```

Comment: It does not work for me. It throughs an error: `The method setXLabelsPadding(int) is undefined for the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`

Comment: You should use an up to date version that you can download here: 
https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/

Comment: You did it! I was originally using Ver1.0.0 and once i got 1.1.0 it worked like a charm!